# A strange effect when click some space in ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

My ListView's ItemTemplate is a very complex Grid, which has multiple rows and columns. The ListView's SelectionMode is Extended.

I met a very strange effect when I click my ListViewItem now. When I click some specific space, such as two gridrows' gap, the item isn't been selected, the ListView will scroll up, then the mouse pointed the next item, no item is selected. This effect only occurs when I click the last item in the view of the ListView.

The ListViewItem's IsSelected property is bound to my model's IsSelected property, and the binding mode is two way. My ItemsSource is ObservableCollection testList, I also have a ObservableCollection which contains the Items which are selected. If double click the item, a new window will be open which display the details of the selected model.

Sometimes, when I single click the space which I mentioned, it even has effect of double click, but an exception is thrown, because more than one item in the selected collection.

Anybody met the strange problem?

Comment: Try posting small sample here replicating an issue.

Comment: @RohitVats this is a very simple sample:http://1drv.ms/1omYdAg